# beamer: creating a special handout using pgfpage

Tags: beamer, pgfpages

I'm trying to make a sort of "trainer's guide" from a beamer presentation using pgfpage (cf. example below), but I have one problem: the handout does not work correctly for the last frame - and I don't know why.

As a workaround, I have to add an empty frame, but I find this not very clean.

Why does the code of `\AtEveryBeginFrame` seem to  be not executed for the last frame?

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper,handout]{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xparse}


\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\beamer@frameslide{\form@everybeginframe@hook    \beamer@checkframetitle}
\def\form@everybeginframe@hook{}
\long\def\AtEveryBeginFrame#1{\g@addto@macro\form@everybeginframe@hook{#1}}
\makeatother

\pgfpagesdeclarelayout{myHandout}{% before action
     }
{ % afteraction
    \setkeys{pgfpagesuselayoutoption}{landscape}
    \pgfpagesphysicalpageoptions{%
        logical pages=2,%
        physical height=29.7cm,%
        physical width=21cm,%
        first logical shipout=2,%
        last logical shipout=2%
    }
    \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{2}{%
        resized width=.5\pgfphysicalwidth,
        resized height=.28\pgfphysicalheight,
        center=\pgfpoint{.37\pgfphysicalwidth}{.8\pgfphysicalheight},%
        border code=\pgfstroke
    }
    \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}{%
        original width=\pgfphysicalwidth,
        original height=\pgfphysicalheight,
        resized width=\pgfphysicalwidth,
        resized height=\pgfphysicalheight,
        center=\pgfpoint{.5\pgfphysicalwidth}{.5\pgfphysicalheight},%
    }
}


\makeatletter

\def\tmp@frame{}

\long\def\@notes{}
\long\def\mynote#1{%
    \long\gdef\@notes{ #1 } %
    \long\xdef\tmp@frame{\insertframenumber}%
} 

\newsavebox{\tmpboxA} % page
\newsavebox{\tmpboxB} % infos
\newsavebox{\tmpboxC} % notes


\AtEveryBeginFrame{%
    \savebox{\tmpboxB}{%
        \parbox[t][7.5cm][t]{5cm}{%
            \Large%
            Frame: \dotfill \tmp@frame \par
            Duration: \dotfill \par
        }
    }
    \savebox{\tmpboxC}{ \parbox{15cm}{\@notes} }
    \savebox{\tmpboxA}[16cm][r]{%
        \parbox{16cm}{%
            \raggedleft
            \usebox{\tmpboxB}\par
            \usebox{\tmpboxC} \long\def\@notes{} 
        }
    }
    \pgfpagesshipoutlogicalpage{1}\copy\tmpboxA
}
\makeatother



\pgfpagesuselayout{myHandout}


\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

\begin{frame}{Frame 1} 
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item<1-> enum 1
    \item<2-> enum 2
    \item<3-> enum 3
    \item<4-> enum 4
    \end{enumerate}

    \mynote{\lipsum[6]}
\end{frame}

\section{Section 2}

\begin{frame}{Frame 1} 
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item<1-> enum 1
    \item<2-> enum 2
    \item<3-> enum 3
    \item<4-> enum 4
    \end{enumerate}

    \mynote{\lipsum[5]}
\end{frame}

%\clearpage
%\begin{frame}
%\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  [I've marked your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) and added a line break in your sample because one `%` hid a closing brace.

Comment: Adding some random text to the argument of `\AtBeginDocument` shows that this command is being excuted.  So there is something wrong in the code that it is calling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some timing issues, that I only partially understand.  But part of the problem is that at the beginning of the frame when you try to construct the surrounding notes, the material for this has not yet been defined.  `pgfpages` is good enough to wait for this, I believe what you are seeing on page 1 is triggered by the code excuted at the beginning of frame 2.  Anyway in the last instance the command doesn't get triggered.  So one solution is to package that code in to a separate command and call it explicitly after the last frame.  (Patching this into `\endframe` does not work, because `beamer' messes around with that command.)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,handout]{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\beamer@frameslide{\form@everybeginframe@hook    \beamer@checkframetitle}
\def\form@everybeginframe@hook{}
\long\def\AtEveryBeginFrame#1{\g@addto@macro\form@everybeginframe@hook{#1}}
\makeatother

\pgfpagesdeclarelayout{myHandout}{% before action
     }
{ % afteraction
    \setkeys{pgfpagesuselayoutoption}{landscape}
    \pgfpagesphysicalpageoptions{%
        logical pages=2,%
        physical height=29.7cm,%
        physical width=21cm,%
        first logical shipout=2,%
        last logical shipout=2%
    }
    \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{2}{%
        resized width=.5\pgfphysicalwidth,
        resized height=.28\pgfphysicalheight,
        center=\pgfpoint{.37\pgfphysicalwidth}{.8\pgfphysicalheight},%
        border code=\pgfstroke
    }
    \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}{%
        original width=\pgfphysicalwidth,
        original height=\pgfphysicalheight,
        resized width=\pgfphysicalwidth,
        resized height=\pgfphysicalheight,
        center=\pgfpoint{.5\pgfphysicalwidth}{.5\pgfphysicalheight},%
    }
}

\makeatletter

\def\tmp@frame{}

\long\def\@notes{}
\long\def\mynote#1{%
    \long\gdef\@notes{ #1 } %
    \long\xdef\tmp@frame{\insertframenumber}%
} 

\newsavebox{\tmpboxA} % page
\newsavebox{\tmpboxB} % infos
\newsavebox{\tmpboxC} % notes

\def\layoutnotes{%
    \savebox{\tmpboxB}{%
        \parbox[t][7.5cm][t]{5cm}{%
            \Large%
            Frame: \dotfill \tmp@frame \par
            Duration: \dotfill \par
        }
    }
    \savebox{\tmpboxC}{ \parbox{15cm}{\@notes} }
    \savebox{\tmpboxA}[16cm][r]{%
        \parbox{16cm}{%
            \raggedleft
            \usebox{\tmpboxB}\par
            \usebox{\tmpboxC} \long\def\@notes{} 
        }
    }
    \pgfpagesshipoutlogicalpage{1}\copy\tmpboxA
}
\AtEveryBeginFrame{\layoutnotes}
\makeatother

\pgfpagesuselayout{myHandout}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

\begin{frame}{Frame 1} 
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item<1-> enum 1
    \item<2-> enum 2
    \item<3-> enum 3
    \item<4-> enum 4
    \end{enumerate}

    \mynote{\lipsum[6]}
\end{frame}

\section{Section 2}

\begin{frame}{Frame 2} 
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item<1-> enum 1
    \item<2-> enum 2
    \item<3-> enum 3
    \item<4-> enum 4
    \end{enumerate}

    \mynote{\lipsum[5]}
\end{frame}

\layoutnotes

\end{document}
```

[image: Sample output]